# Work done by spring force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, free-body-diagram, spring

Consider a spring connected to  blocks on it's ends lying on smooth horizontal table. 
Now let the right end  block   be displaced $x_1$ and left end be displaced $x_2$ from the mean position such that 
the work done by spring is $ -\frac{1}{2}k(x_1+x_2)^2$ 
(=$-\Delta PE$)
But my question is if we consider the the free body of a single block then $F=-kx$ acts on the block and the work done by that force is $-\frac{1}{2}k(x_1+x_2)^2$ (I understand why work done on say right block is not $(-\frac{1}{2}kx_1)^2$ as if we consider right end block at any instant the ‘$x$’ term in the force is total extension of the spring at that instant) and as there are two blocks so total work is 
$=2\cdot(\frac{1}{2}k(x_1+x_2)^2)$
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How could a spring connect to one block in opposite sides. Or is the spring is curved?

Answer (score 1):

In the scenario you are considering it is no longer true that $F_1=-k x_1$ because the other side may move and change the force irrespective of $x_1$. So $F_1=-k (x_1+x_2)$.

When calculating the work done by $F_1$ you have to include both $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the calculation of the force, but only $x_1$ in the calculation of the distance. Similarly for $F_2$.

So when you calculate the work done by the individual forces you get a complicated function that depends on their joint motion. In the end, however, you will always find that they add up to $-\Delta PE$, but you can make the work done by either individual force take any value you want by appropriately moving the other end.

Comment: So do you mean work done on say right block when it is displaced by x is $\int_0^xk(x_1+x_2)dx_1=-1/2kx_1^2 -kxx_2$